# Can I post a question already posted on Travel.SE to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, asking-questions, cross-posting

In case I haven't received any answers for a question at Travel.SE, can I post it at Stack Overflow as it has a bigger community?

Are there chances of it getting an off topic flag if it is not related to programming and more specific to travel related?

Comment: You have to ask?

Comment: Travel and programming aren't the same thing. So NO.

Comment: Can I go into the women's restroom if the men's is full? Um...

Comment: @Mysticial you can if you are a woman ;-)

Comment: We can't stop you trying, but rest assured that you will be down-voted and your question will be closed quickly because SO has a vast and active community that spots such anomalies and deals with them severely.

Comment: I am already banging my head against the wall as to why did I even dared to ask this here. Already a -7, no idea if I will be left with any more points by tomorrow !! I am clueless as I cannot remove this post as it has answers with it !!

Comment: In any case, sorry if I sounded kinda snarky. But essentially that's what it is. No you can't post a blatantly off-topic question on SO for whatever reason you have.

Comment: @AnmolSaraf Don't worry about it. Reputation on meta.stackoverflow is meaningless. Votes here work differently and express agreement or disagreement - nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Can you phrase it as a programming question?  ...any chance you're a travelling *salesman*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a question is not related to programming, it will almost certainly be closed very quickly; Stack Overflow is for programming-related topics, only. The other Stack Exchange sites exist for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

If it's related primarily to travel, it will almost certainly be closed as off topic on SO.

It's a bit like the old joke about the guy looking for his wife's wedding ring -- looking under the street light because the light's better, even though she lost it 100 yards away.

Answer (score 3):

Before posting *anywhere* you should read the Help pages, https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for Stack Overflow.

This is clearly not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

However, you've only been waiting an hour for your question on Travel. Why not have a little more patience?

Furthermore, you already have at least one off-topic vote on Travel. Have you read [their Help page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? Maybe you should take a look and reword your question if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is a good fit on travel.stackexchange.com, then it certainly isn't one on Stackoverflow. It doesn't matter that it has a bigger community, SO is for programming related questions, as seen here: [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

#### NO

If you ask a question about *X* on a site for *X*, it is definitely a bad idea to re-ask the question on a site about *Y*!

In general, only cross post to another site if:

1. That site is more specific than the first
2. That site is a superset of the first, but much more active

> Are there chances of getting it a off topic flag if it is not related with programming and more specific to travel related.

Absolute certainty. That's the exact purpose for which the off topic flag was designed.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your question is not

- a specific programming problem

if you need help with

- a software algorithm

...(to find the lowest airfare for a route covering 10 places?), or

- software tools commonly used by programmers

...(to get an IDE to do custom syntax-highlighting to highlight all instances of the word "beach" on your itinerary?), or

- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

...(to get an idea of what kind of skills you might need for a certain new position, if you bought a one-way ticket?), then sure!

Otherwise...no.